# How to change WebsiteLayout without going to a new Homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple website which at the moment just displays a popup which asks me to login. It then connects to an API to log me in. If everything worked out it gives me a success/done callback which lets me work from there (simple jQuery APIi guess).

After I logged in the popup goes away (no problem here) and my back layout changes to the site I want. I don't want to redirect to another link or another HTML file. I want to say "change the body you have at the moment and use this one" or something like that. A coworker of mine does it like that and I want to learn how it works.

Thanks for the responses. I don't think I need code here but if someone needs code 
I can provide it.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to describe a Single Page Architecture (SPA) site. The basic idea is that when an AJAX request is made you update the HTML of the current page to reflect whatever the response requires.

Comment: Damn thanks !, i needed the word for it, i was searching for Templating and such but just found basic how to website. Just needed the Word so i can search for it. Thanks helped me out alot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a Single Page Architecture (SPA) as a keyword for Reasearching it will help everybody who has the same Question.